# Book about a magical castle powered by a spinning crystal

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I read this book a long time ago. Only remember bits.

1. Magical castle with a spinning crystal that powers it
2. A fight happened that cause the spinning crystal to start a slight wobble
3. Main character had a ring that he could detect any person within the castle and could also activate the magical drawbridge

Comment: How long ago is "a long time ago"? Three years? The 60s?

Comment: Would have been 5 to 7 years ago.